# Which generation is my iPod touch ?

Tags: ipod-touch, ipod

It has 64gb and its model no is a1367, does anyone know what model this is?

I have tried to type in the serial no but it is saying its not valid. I want to sell this as I dont need it anymore however I need to know what gen it is.

Comment: @JakeGould The person stated that they typed in the serial number and were unable to find any information on it.

Comment: @JakeGould Got it :) Just wanted to make sure.

Answer (score 2):

It is a [4th generation iPod touch](http://www.everymac.com/ultimate-mac-lookup/?search_keywords=A1367).

Answer (score -1):

Probably you have 4th generation of an iPod touch (at least google says so)